# Login via rest using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

The senario is that I just want to do a simple login using

```
var test = {login: 'testuser', password: 'asd'};
Restangular.one('/auth/login').post(test);
```

it makes a request to "auth/login/[object%20Object]" and I get a 404?

using this code it works just fine:

```
xmlhttp.send('{"login":"testuser", "password":"asd"}’);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `customPOST(test)` and the data should be passed appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The code was actually working.. error was in the API!